# SaveDialog file exist?

Tags: c#

I use this code to save an avi file. When I create a new file, it's no problem.
 But When I choose an existing file, It does not work and `saveFileDialog` still shows.

I have set `saveDialog.OverwritePrompt` and `saveDialog.CheckFileExists` is true, but it is not ok. If I set `saveDialog.OverwritePrompt` is false it runs, but it does show overwrite warning

How can I solve this?

```
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
DialogResult dgResult = saveDialog.ShowDialog();

if (dgResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
     exportAvi(saveDialog.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the exportAvi() function. You are not allowing for the file to be overwritten. I cannot see your exportAvi() function so I cannot tell you what is wrong exactly. If you post your exportAvi() function I can help you further.

> saveDialog.OverwritePrompt - will only prompt the user if they want to overwrite. It will not overwrite the file. You have to handle this in your code.
>
> saveDialog.CheckFileExists - will only check if the file exists.

Check your export function and make sure you are setting the overwrite parameter to True.

Comment: No this cannot be correct because the prompt happens before the code control reach's the ` if (dgResult == DialogResult.OK)` ie before the call to `exportAvi`

Answer (score 1):

This code works - if I choose to overwerite an existing file it shows me the Prompt:

```
    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
    DialogResult dgResult = saveDialog.ShowDialog();


    if (dgResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //exportAvi(saveDialog.FileName);
    }
```

[Window Title]
Confirm Save As

[Content]
XYZ.txt already exists.
Do you want to replace it?

[Yes] [No]

Comment: may be it's depend on my environment?. I have waited very long time to it's shown